# Why altering column from varchar(50) to int requires more space

Tags: sql-server, int, varchar

I imported a table into my MS SQL database. The table is quite large and fills the database almost completely. The import tool I used saved my numeric columns as `varchar(50)`, but I want them to be integer. Therefore, I altered the column to be `int`.

```
alter table <my_table> alter column <my_column> int
```

As far as I know, the `int` column should take less disc space, but the above query fails on error of insufficient free space.

What causes this issue and is there any possible workaround?

Comment: What do you mean?, an `INT` goes up to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647), a `VARCHAR(50)` can go up to `'99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'`

Comment: I think under the hood it will be adding another column, populating it, then do a switcheroo at the end. Can you not provide more space, even temporarily?

Comment: _"is there any possible workaround"_ - clean up your hard drive.

Comment: what is the total error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer column uses 4 bytes.

Based on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), the size of a varchar column is easily calculated:

> The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.
>   The ISO synonyms for varchar are charvarying or charactervarying.

Hence, if your column consists mostly of single digits, then that only uses 3 bytes.  `NULL` values even use fewer values (I think just the two length bytes).  Of course, this suggests that you can use `smallint` or `tinyint`, saving even more space.

Comment: Thanks, my column is mostly NULLs, but may contain values larger than `smallint`, so your answer seem to clear the issue. Do you think it would be a good idea to leave the `varchar` and use `cast` when doing calculations?

Comment: @pajonk . . . In general, a byte here or there is not a big deal.  If you have a million rows, then you are talking about only a few megabytes of additional storage.  I should say:  *sometimes* it does make a difference, but usually such optimizations are not necessary.